# SQL left join to return null entries for multiple criteria

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables. One called tbl_id and one called tbl_values.

tbl_id is as below:

```
property_id | Name  
1           | Height   
2           | Depth  
3           | Length  
4           | Weight
```

tbl_values is as below:

```
property_id | submission_ID | Value  
2           | 100           | 123.5  
3           | 100           | 22.4  
1           | 200           | 548.0  
3           | 200           | 34.2  
4           | 200           | 17.9
```

The output that I want is this:

```
submission_ID | Name   | Value  
100           | Height | NULL  
100           | Depth  | 123.5  
100           | Length | 22.4  
100           | Weight | NULL  
200           | Height | 548.0  
200           | Depth  | NULL  
200           | Length | 34.2  
200           | Weight | 17.9
```

The SQL that I have so far is this:

```
SELECT t2.submission_ID, t1.Name, t2.Value  
FROM tbl_id t1  
LEFT JOIN tbl_values t2 ON t2.property_id = t1.property_id AND submission_ID IN (100,200)  
ORDER BY t2.submission_ID
```

This SQL, run in SQL server 2014, returns the values that I want but not the NULLs separately for each submission_ID. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t2.submission_ID,
       t1.Name,
       t3.Value
FROM tbl_id t1
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT submission_ID
    FROM tbl_values
) t2
LEFT JOIN tbl_values t3
    ON t1.property_id   = t3.property_id AND
       t2.submission_id = t3.submission_id
ORDER BY t2.submission_ID,
         t1.property_id
```

I have tested this query locally in Postgres (I don't have SQL Server) and it appears to be working.  The trick here is the first join, which generates every combination between submission IDs and names.  Then, we do a second join to bring in the actual values which matched.

Comment: Didn't know. Just did.